# Configure & connect to Wi-Fi using ADB on Android 5.1.1

Tags: wi-fi, adb, 5.1-lollipop

I'm using Nexus 4 with Android 5.1.1. I need to connect to Wi-Fi router in my automation. For that I need to use ADB interface. I connected to mobile using ADB. I also configured the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file and copied it to `/data/misc/wifi/`.

```
chmod 644 wpa_supplicant.conf
chown wifi.wifi wpa_supplicant.conf
```

When I execute the `adb svc wifi enable`, phone doesn't connect to the SSID  I have specified in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

I have created the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file using the existing `wpa_supplicant.conf` file. (Just to make sure I do not mess the format, but different SSID and password with same WPA-PSK method.)

Can anyone guide me what I need to change or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `adb svc wifi enable` -- it cannot work. Please [edit]. Anyhow, `adb shell svc wifi enable` would activate the Wi-Fi only. It doesn't make sure that the device would connect to an SSID of your choice. Show us your new `wpa_supplicant.conf` file (use a paste service). Not sure, but you may have to use the service `wifi` unless there is only one SSID in your file and you're in its range.

Comment: What kind of automation are you working on? Give us some basic context.

Comment: @Firelord    My wpa_supplicant.conf as as follows.  disable_scan_offload=1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
update_config=1
device_name=occam
manufacturer=LGE
model_name=Nexus 4
model_number=Nexus 4
serial_number=0221f14e1188d36d
device_type=10-0050F204-5
config_methods=physical_display virtual_push_button
pmf=1
external_sim=1
tdls_external_control=1

network={
 ssid="TestWiFi"
 psk="Test1234"
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
 priority=1
}

Comment: @Firelord  The automation is for one app which requires me to connect to first Wifi Gateway in initial stage and later on to another Wifi Gateway. The issue is I am using Calabash to automate the app. I do not have clue how to switch between the 2 wifi networks in automation. So I am using adb. Calabash cannot access system options.

Comment: Note that you can't edit the conf file directly over adb. For giggles, leave the conf file up in vi and then try changing your wifi password using the phone. Shocking! Now reboot.